# How can I multiply all the elements in a list with a given constant?

Tags: python, list, multiplication

```
 [[[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0,-7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0,-7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]]]
```

I want to multiply all the numbers in this list using Python with a constant (say (-1)), but the list still has the original format. I was trying to do that with 3 'for' loops, but is there a short way I can do this? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm using Python:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can multiply all of the numbers by a constant. For more advanced operations, you may want to look into `np.vectorize` or `np.apply`

```py
import numpy as np

nested_list = [[[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0,-7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0,-7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]], [[-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0], [-7.0, -7.0]]]
numpy_list = np.array(nested_list)

negated_list = -1 * numpy_list
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helps:)

Comment: If this was helpful to you, can you upvote the answer and accept it? I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: I've upvoted but I don't have enough point to make it appear. Thanks!!

Comment: @Zhengrong. You do now

Comment: Oh great! Thanks:)